# Python Calculator with lists and loops

Tags: python

I am trying to create a calculator program that takes user input and stores it in a list and perform the calculation based on their selection. However, I keep running across an error for line 31 saying

> `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

Here is the code:

```py
import math

def printIntro():
    print("This is a simple calculator.")
print("Select an operation:\n1) Add\n2) Subtract\n3) Divide\n4) Multiply")

while True:
    operator = input("Enter your choice of + - / *: \n")

    if operator in('+', '-', '/', '*'):
        #continue asking for numbers until user ends
        #store numbers in an array

        list = []
        num = float(input("What are your numbers?: "))
        for n in range(num):
            numbers = float(input("What are your numbers?: "))
        list.append(numbers)
        if n == '':
            break

        if operator == '+':
            print(add(list))

        if operator == '-':
            print(subtract(list))

        if operator == '/':
            print(divide(list))

        if operator == '*':
            print(multiply(list))
    else:
        break
```

Comment: An iterator must be of type integer hence this line fails `for n in range(num):` since you explicitly convert `num` to float. Use `int()` instead.

Comment: There are a number of issues that I noticed with your code. Some of them are mentioned below so I'll just add one concern from a quick read. Your prompt is confusing. When you ask "what are your numbers?" that triggers a request for multiple numbers. Are these comma separated? Space separated? Regardless of what how it is, `float()` will not work. You can't take a float of a string that is itself multiple values. You need to parse that into separate elements first. For example, trt `float("5, 10")`

Comment: Do you follow a specific [tutorial](https://pythonguides.com/make-a-calculator-in-python/), book, etc? Pay attention to the __indents__ (`print` on line 5) and make code-reading/debugging easier when keeping loops short, e.g. __extract the loop body__ into a function.

Answer (score 1):

Python's [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) method accepts an **integer**.

The error is due to the fact that you convert the input to float in `num = float(..)` before giving it to `range(num)`.

I think in the line where you try to get the number from input causes it:

```py
num = float(input("What are your numbers?: "))
```

It should work with (I also fixed the prompt message):

```py
num = int(input("How many numbers you have?: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

for n in range(int(num)): cast num as int inside the for loop such as this. There is a similar comment to this above but here is the fixed code.